# Trouble with piping

Tags: bash, pipe, diff

Why I can't do something like:

```
tail -n 5 small.txt | diff small.txt
```

I want to pass the execution result of the first command like second argument of the second, not stand alone input. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `tail -n 5 small.txt | diff small.txt -`.

From `man diff`:

> If a FILE is '-', read standard input.

The `-` method shows you how to do correctly what you wanted to do. But the method below teaches you something that will make your (shell) life easier:

```
diff small.txt <(tail -n 5 small.txt)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! What is the name of this technique?

Comment: from diff manual..

FILES are 'FILE1 FILE2' or 'DIR1 DIR2' or 'DIR FILE...' or 'FILE... DIR'. If --from-file or --to-file is given, there are no restrictions on FILE(s). If a FILE is '-', read standard input. Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.

Comment: @argle It is buried deep at the end of the man page.

Comment: I also noticed that it works well with cat: ```echo 'one' | cat small.txt -```. Maybe it's not only diff feature?

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

```
  diff small.txt <(tail -n 5 small.txt)
```

Comment: Voting for this one for using process substitution :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't write the pipeline in the way you suggest is that the `diff` utility expects two input files on the command line and won't by default read from its standard input stream (the output from `tail`).

You may instruct `diff` to read from standard input by just adding `-` as second "file" argument (or first, depending on what order you want to compare the files in):

```
tail -n 5 small.txt | diff small.txt -
```

`diff` will detect the `-` filename and read from the `tail` command instead of from a second file.  This is semantics implemented by a few utilities such as `diff`, `cat`, `paste`, etc. but is not universal (the shell doesn't know about `-` "being the same as standard input").

In `bash` and other shells that supports *process substitution* using `<( ... )`, one may instruct the shell to create a temporary file (or FIFO) that contains the output from a particular command:

```
diff small.txt <( tail -n 5 small.txt )
```

This is *essentially* (but not technically) the same as

```
tail -n 5 small.txt >tmpfile
diff small.txt tmpfile
rm -f tmpfile
```